# Django messages not displaying on webpage

Tags: django-forms

I created and imported the usual "django.contrib" from message, attached is the code snippet for my view.py page and register.html.When I tried to register a new user, I"m not getting the warning message on the webpage instead all I get is "<django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x00000230B847FEE0>" i don't know what am doing wrong. Please help Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5zbA.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

messages in django is a class , for display messages you need to iterate on it

```
{% if messages %}
   <ul class="messages">
   {% for message in messages %}
      <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

[django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages)